# Is it possible to run SIP client and server on the same machine?

Tags: android, sip

I am running a sip server on an Android machine using uSipServer app, can i also run a SIP client (connected to that same server) such as linphone on the same device?

if yes, what configuration of both sip server and client should work?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible as long as you use different SIP ports when sending/ receiving SIP messages (RTP ports should be chosen automatically).